# Cable lacing in spaceflight, when was waxed cord forbidden?

Tags: nasa, spacecraft

During the sixties of last century traditional cable lacing was done using a thin cord, traditionally made of waxed linen. The wax should improve knot retention.
[image]

[image]

From [NASA-STD-8739-4](https://snebulos.mit.edu/projects/reference/NASA-Generic/NASA-STD-8739-4.pdf).

Using waxed tape or cord is forbidden now:

[image]

From [NASA workmanship standards](https://workmanship.nasa.gov/lib/insp/2%20books/links/sections/401%20General%20Requirements.html) Released: 04.05.2002.

There is now braided fiberglass lacing tape (A-A-52083 MIL- T-43435) with silicone finish for improved knot retention made from fireproof materials, [see](http://www.gudebrod.com/electronic/Braid_Lacing_Tape.htm)

**But when was the usage of waxed lacing forbidden for spaceflight  applications?**

Comment: To help bound it: it was ok for (unmanned) payload in 1981.  It was not ok in the early 2000’s, perhaps 2004.

Comment: @BobJacobsen the workmanship standards were released 2002, so it was forbidden in 2004.

Comment: I would guess that out-gassing is the issue.